# Labelling of noun components of a verb

Tags: verbs, compounds

In a verbal construction, like *scuba diving*, what is 'scuba' held to be?

> I like scuba diving.

Above, 'scuba diving' is a gerund.

> I like to scuba dive.

Above, 'to scuba dive' is the infinitive.

Is 'scuba' considered a noun adjunct in a verbal construction like this?

And there are plenty of other examples like this:

- *to skate board*
- *to spear fish*
- *to space walk*
- *to home school*

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scuba-diving) classes 'scuba diving' (in the nounal usage, at least) as a 'noun' (hence an open compound), and 'skateboard' in either verbal or nounal usage as a solid compound. Without comment on where the components originated.

Comment: No, not really; _scuba_ certainly refers to a noun, but it's been locked into the compound and isn't really functioning as a noun syntactically. If you wanted to class these compound verbs as having nominal sources, that would be reasonable. But it wouldn't distinguish the locative  compound _space walk_ 'walk in space' from the instrumental compound _spear fish_ 'fish with a spear'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Scuba* (occasionally SCUBA) is an acronym, standing for **s**elf-**c**ontained **u**nderwater **b**reathing **a**pparatus, and it is occasionally used as a noun meaning that type of equipment. For example, in [*Reef Fishes of Hong Kong*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VWX19IN0630C&pg=PA1&dq=%22scuba%20and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyq_fZ3dfNAhUFZCYKHc5bCb8Q6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=%22scuba%20and%22&f=false) by Y Sadovy and A Cornish

> Fishes were recorded by underwater visuaL census surveys, using
>   **SCUBA**, and collected by fishing gears such as nets, hooks, traps and anaesthetics.

[More often its used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scuba%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cscuba%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscuba%20diving%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20divers%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20diver%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20gear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20dive%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20equipment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20tank%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20tanks%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscuba%20lessons%3B%2Cc0) to modify other nouns, *dive*, *tank*, lessons, and even the somewhat-redundant *equipment*. In these cases it is thus lexically a noun but functionally a noun modifier, a role going by the name *adjunct noun* or *attributive noun*.

When *scuba* is combined with a verb, usually with forms of *to dive*, it forms a *compound verb*, a *noun*+*verb* form in which the noun is subsumed into a digram that functions as a verb:

> I will **scuba dive** at the Great Barrier Reef tomorrow.